# Notice: Undefined variable: today and tomorrow(Variable's) in .. on line 6

Tags: php, mysql

I want to add `$today` and `$tomorrow` to my mysql but it's have Notice error. 
When I use this format it's working: '`2013-10-04`'.

This is my code :

```
<?php
$date = "";
$saat = "";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM calendar  WHERE starttime >= '$today' AND starttime < '$tomorrow' and username= '$user' order by starttime ASC  ";
 $result = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql); 

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  $date =  $row['StartTime']."<br />";
  $date = date("j F Y ", strtotime($row['StartTime']));
  $saat = date("H", strtotime($row['StartTime']));
  echo $date . "At  " . $saat."<br />";
  }
?>
```

This is my code I want to use for my dates:

```
<?php
    $tomorrow = mktime(0,0,0,date("m"),date("d")+1,date("Y"));
    echo "Tomorrow is ".date("Y-m-d", $tomorrow). "<br />";
    $today = date("Y-m-d");
    echo "Today is " .$today . "<br>";
  ?>
```

What do I need to do ? Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't build SQL queries by concatenating strings anyway.

Comment: Where did you initialize $today and $tomorrow in your first script? What is the link between first and second script?

Answer (score 1):

include the below file in the above file at the top.

**Syntax:**

```
include("file_name.php");
```

You can use `require` also:

```
require("path_to_file/file_name.php");
```

And then you can use the variables of the below file in the above file.

Comment: both of them in the same page i don't need to include

Comment: @Farzadfm then you should put the code in that file in which you want to access it or you can use the session to store the value.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$today = strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));
$tomorrow = date('Y-m-d', $today + (3600 * 30) ) ;
echo $tomorrow;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try it this way.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM calendar  WHERE starttime >= '".$today."' AND starttime < '".$tomorrow."' and username= '".$user."' order by starttime ASC";
```

If these are two different files, you should use on the top of first script following:

```
require_once($second_script_name);
```

Are you getting error from PHP or SQL?

Comment: Don't you think this should be a comment instead of answer?

Comment: Ok, so try, after declaring and filling $sql variable with query, to echo this variable: 
echo $sql; 

You can see the whole query and can determine where is the problem. You can post it to comment under this and we can take a look on it.